# How do I write mocha tests where one tests depends on the result for the next test?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, mocha.js

```
describe("Company Controller", function() {
  var apiUrl;

  beforeEach(function(done) {
    apiUrl = "http://localhost:3001";

    done();
  });

  it('should register a client without error and return an API key', function(done) {
    request({
      uri: apiUrl + '/api/v1/company',
      method: 'POST',
      json: true,
      form: {
        name: 'My Company'
      }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
      should.not.exist(err);
      res.statusCode.should.eql(200);
      body.status.should.eql('ok');
      should.exist(body.company.api_key);
      done();
    });
  });

  it('should generate a new API key for a company', function(done) {
    // NEED THE client_id generated in the previous test

  });

  after(function(done) {
    Company.remove().exec();
    done();
  });
});
```

How do I get the client_id in the next test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally speaking, making tests with side effects is a brittle practice. Do this often enough, you'll start to encounter some very difficult-to-debug errors where your test suite fails even though every test runs in isolation, and the error messages won't be any help. Ideally every test should "leave the campground" in the same state that it found it.

If you're really insistent on doing this, you could of course set a global variable. Some other options include:

- Merging the two tests. Yes, this violates a principle of Single-Assertion-Per-Test that some people hold, but I think the Avoid-Side-Effects principle trumps that one.
- Put the registration in the beforeEach function. Yes, by doing this you'll be registering multiple clients per test suite run. This is still my preferred approach.

Comment: I like putting the registration in `beforeEach`, but then how do I test that registration happened?

Comment: The beforeEach could set a few variables (similar to how it sets apiUrl). Those variables can be asserted against in that first basic test, and then used by other tests. Alternatively, many test frameworks (possibly including Mocha) will let you run assertions inside the beforeEach. So you could potentially run those basic assertions as part of the beforeEach, and not even have a separate test for them.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a stub. For example [sinonjs](http://sinonjs.org). This way you use a fake function to test another. You don't need to use `beforeEach` and `afterEach` if you only need to stub the function once you can define it inside the `it` function.

```
describe("Company controller", function() {
  describe("dependantFunction()", function() {
    var stub;

    beforeEach(function() {
      stub = sinon.stub(module, 'targetFunction');

      stub.onCall(0).callsArgWith(1, ...some valid results...);
      stub.onCall(1).callsArgWith(1, ...some expected error...);
      stub.throws();
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      stub.restore();
    });

    it("should do something", function() {
       var result;

       module.targetfunction(null, result);
       dependantfunction(result);
       ....your tests here....
    });

    it("should do something else", function() {
      ...
    });
  });
});
```